# How to integrate Tripit on ios?

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth

I need to add to my iPhone app a log-in btn through [Tripit](http://tripit.github.com/api/doc/v1/index.html). 
I understand that I need to connect through [OAuth](http://googlemac.blogspot.co.il/2010/09/oauth-sign-in-controllers-for-ios-and.html) and then integrate Tripit API.

But I don't understand what is going on, which part of the code (of both OAuth and Trippit) should I implement? and where (is the whole OAuth code with the log-in supposed to be called when pressing the log-in btn?).

Does anyone have maybe an example? Or a lighter explanation for the API for ios?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is used to connect your app to the user's Tripit account. After connecting, you will have OAuth tokens to store and use when making the API requests. Here is some [information from a Tripit person](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/api_tripit/anneDbGGOHw/uHRrG8OQXJwJ) on suggestions for OAuth and JSON libraries to use on iOS.

Comment: Thanks!
I still had trouble with the technical use, but luckily I fount a Tripit xCode example: 
https://github.com/tripit/objective_c_binding_v1
Noe I'm trying to figure out how to integrate it into the existing project...